# What Are Your Favourite ASP.NET Add Ons / Tools To Improve Productivity & Code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm wondering what other tools / frameworks / Add Ons people use to improve their productivity / development speed when coding in ASP.NET.

I just use VS2008 on its own but wanted to find out what other people use with VS2008 AND WHY??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use:

[GhostDoc](https://submain.com/GhostDoc/): GhostDoc is a free add-in for Visual Studio that automatically generates XML
documentation comments for C#. Either by using existing documentation inherited
from base classes or implemented interfaces, or by deducing comments from
name and type of e.g. methods, properties or parameters.

[CodeRush Xpress for Visual Studio](https://www.devexpress.com/products/coderush/): CodeRush Xpress is freely available to all Visual Studio 2008 developers and offers a comprehensive suite of tools that enable you and your team to simplify and shape complex code - making it easier to read and less costly to maintain.

[CoolCommands](https://web.archive.org/web/20210122043703/http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2007/12/12/coolcommands-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx): It contains lots of cool stuff, but I mainly use the font-functionalities like: 'Demo Font' or 'Wheel Font Sizing'. E.g. Demo Font easily switches the font to a size which is perfect for giving demos on a beamer. If you disable it again, your font size is switched back to its original size.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), [IE Developer ToolBar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) and [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) improves your speed if you're working on javascript and css on your project. Also [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is good tool for debugging puposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this counts, but we use [CruiseControl.NET](http://ccnet.thoughtworks.com/) for our buildserver, which in the long run, helps productivity as well.

I have used [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) for a while, and although it does improve productivity, I eventually uninstalled it since it made my Visual Studio too slow. Although I have to admint, that was almost two years ago, so it may have improved since then.

Answer (score 0):

Mine tools are: [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com) and [Refactor](http://www.devexpress.com), as well as [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/).

Answer (score 0):

*[Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/overview.aspx?key=web)*: can open a Visual Studio .Sln file, but is focused on design.
And it is included in my MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 0):

*Google Chrome*: Has a very nice "Inspect Element" item on the context menu. Amongst other things, the screen will learn you very easy where the CSS properties are coming from.

Comment: Why would you use this when you can use FireFox & FireBug??

Comment: Because Chrome is the better browser (o-oh starting religious war here). In Chrome you do not need plugins to let this work. I hate plugins, plugin == invitation to spyware. IMHO FireFox is as bad as IE, a big slow memory eater. And you need plugins to make it do what I want it to do.

Comment: Sorry, but as of today the inspect in Chrome doesn't stand a chance to FireBug. I use Chrome for most of my browsing, but let's be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of ReSharper, Web Developer Toolkit and Firebug in Firefox, Chrome, GhostDoc and Fiddler (particularly useful for JSON requests). Oh and YSlow.